# making a set of objects drag together with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery object which has a bunch of things in it.

```
var $item = $();
$("div.t2").click(function(){
    $item = $item.add(this);
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
});
```

Now i want to move the items all togeher fluidly, maintaining their relationship to each other.

I was going to use draggable, and was thinking to do something like:  parse though $items and store current position, then on end apply to the mouses difference.  How would i you all do it?

I was trying to do something like:

```
$item.each(function(){
   //content
});
```

but it isnt seeming to select stuff, and likewise, something simple like:

```
$item.each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","green");
    });
});
```

which also isnt working for selecting before i even start dragging the whole group about.

Should i take the entire jquery object and clone it into a new div, and then move the div... then reapply positioning that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this, i created an array of jquery objects to encapsulate the selected objects.  (more or less maintaining pointers to the objects etc).  Then when you are dragging, you will do some fancy little magic.

create 2 new attributes for the content, offx and offy for each of the dom elements.  that way you do something as follows:

```
.draggable({
   start: function(){

      $array.each(function(){
         $(this).attr('offx', $(this).attr('left') - $(event.target).attr('left'));
         $(this).attr('offy', $(this).attr('top') - $(event.target).attr('top'));
      });
   },
   drag: function(){
      $array.each(function(){
         $(this).attr("left", $(event.target).attr("left") + $(this).attr("offx"));
         $(this).attr("top", $(event.target).attr("top") + $(this).attr("offy"));
      });
   }
});
```

that way, while it is dragging, it will update all the items in relation to the selected object.